# malloc - Heap Chunk History

Tags: malloc, heap-memory

Would like to find out how we are able to find out which line of code within a program executed `malloc()` that resulted in a heap chunk being allocated.

I am able to use `heap` from pwndbg to find out the heap chunks, but unfortunately I have been able to find out which part of the program (in my case, I am using QEMU) called `malloc()`.

I found `info malloc-history` using Google search but it doesn't work out.

Thank you!

---

Edit to show 2 screenshots:

Ideal heap chunk. This chunk has the `NON_MAIN_ARENA` bit enabled (as compared to the non-ideal heap chunk). This heap chunk is ideal for me because it contains a heap and text address that I want:

[image: Ideal heap chunk for having NON_MAIN_ARENA bit enabled because that chunk segment contains a heap and text address that I want]

Non-ideal heap chunk. This chunk does not have the `NON_MAIN_ARENA` bit enabled, and does not contain the address that I want:

[image: Non-ideal heap chunk because that chunk segment does not contain the address that I want]

Running QEMU on multiple occasions (with the same steps) yields either one of the 2 chunks above. I am not sure how to deterministically get the ideal heap chunk.

Comment: Have you tried valgrind?

Comment: @StewartSmith Thanks a lot for suggesting that - I just tried it out! Unfortunately it does not seem to be able to read anonymous memory segments...? I am interested in the heap chunks within it.

Comment: Maybe some more context is needed? Valgrind should be able to show you all userland allocations done by the program.

Comment: @StewartSmith I think you're right. I've updated my original post with 2 screenshots (that hopefully adds clarity). Thank you so much for your replies! I really appreciate it.